# Как зафиксировать первую строку в таблице и прокручивать вместе с содержимым страницы?

Tags: html, css

Такой вопрос. Имеется таблица.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать, чтобы первая строчка фиксировалась и прокручивалась вместе с содержимым страницы?

Answer (score 4):

дайте например,ИД (кепка) к первой строке и жаваскриптом:

```
var div = $('#kepka');
        var start = $(div).offset().top;

        $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
            var p = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
            $(div).css('margin-left','-5px');
            $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
        });
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/k6tAv/)

Comment: усложню вопрос. если у меня на странице 2 таблицы и я хочу сделать на каждой такое? :) ну ессно если проскроллить до конца первой таблицы оно перестанет быть прикрепленной :)

а так, спасибо за пример.

Comment: @thunder, пользуйтесь :first или eq(0).